# C++ Can I declare a Struct using a variable value as the Struct name?

Tags: c++, struct

I have declared a simple struct for use in my program. When I go to create a variable based on that struct in my main program, I would like to name it based on a name I have already stored in a variable.

Is this possible?

e.g. my struct is declared like this:

```
struct myGreatStruct{
int foo;
int fum;
}
```

then later in my program, a user inputs a their name which gets stored in a variable called someVariable

and finally I need to use that variable value to name my struct:

```
myGreatStruct someVariable;
```

Comment: So, you want to use runtime data (user input) to name your variable? Variable names is a compile time construct that disappears during compilation, so no, this is not possible. Maybe you want to use a `std::map`?

Answer (score 3):

Use an associative container e.g. `std::unordered_map`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::unordered_map<std::string, myGreatStruct> vars;
    std::string var_name;

    std::cout << "Input var name" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> var_name;

    vars[var_name].foo = 1; // using the name that the user gave
}
```